# How can I build PlutoGrid rows dynamically from a Flutter ListView?

Tags: flutter

The `PlutoGrid` docs show row definitions like below. How can I create the rows dynamically from a List of a flutter class? I can't find any builder method or example code anywhere showing how to do this.

```
final List<PlutoRow> rows = [
    PlutoRow(
      cells: {
        'id': PlutoCell(value: 'user1'),
        'name': PlutoCell(value: 'Mike'),
        'age': PlutoCell(value: 20),
        'role': PlutoCell(value: 'Programmer'),
        'joined': PlutoCell(value: '2021-01-01'),
        'working_time': PlutoCell(value: '09:00'),
        'salary': PlutoCell(value: 300),
      },
    ),
    PlutoRow(
      cells: {
        'id': PlutoCell(value: 'user2'),
        'name': PlutoCell(value: 'Jack'),
        'age': PlutoCell(value: 25),
        'role': PlutoCell(value: 'Designer'),
        'joined': PlutoCell(value: '2021-02-01'),
        'working_time': PlutoCell(value: '10:00'),
        'salary': PlutoCell(value: 400),
      },
    ),
    PlutoRow(
      cells: {
        'id': PlutoCell(value: 'user3'),
        'name': PlutoCell(value: 'Suzi'),
        'age': PlutoCell(value: 40),
        'role': PlutoCell(value: 'Owner'),
        'joined': PlutoCell(value: '2021-03-01'),
        'working_time': PlutoCell(value: '11:00'),
        'salary': PlutoCell(value: 700),
      },
    ),
  ];
```

Here is one of several classes which I wish to display in a Pluto grid. I will not display the id field.

```
  int userId = 0;
  String fullName = '';
  double amount = 0;

  ActivitiesSummaryReportLine(
      {this.userId = 0, this.fullName = '', this.amount = 0});

  ActivitiesSummaryReportLine.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['user_id'];
    fullName = json['full_name'];
    amount = (json['amount'] as num).toDouble();
  }
```

Comment: Add the source class you want to create the row from. Add it to the question let's see.

Comment: okey. i get what you trying to do now. kindly add the raw json response to the question. You can just put a significant part of it or upload it somewhere and add the link.

Comment: I don't have an actual response at present. I'm just working from code.

Comment: You question clearly shows desired result.  It doesn't show   any significant portion initial data or structure.

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically add new rows to an empty list or convert your objects using [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/Iterable/map.html):

```java
// Load your data
final lines = [
  ActivitiesSummaryReportLine(...),
  ActivitiesSummaryReportLine(...),
];

// Create PlutoRows in a loop
final rows = <PlutoRow>[];
for (var line in lines) {
  rows.add(
    PlutoRow(
      cells: {
        'userId': PlutoCell(value: line.userId),
        'fullName': PlutoCell(value: line.fullName),
        'amount': PlutoCell(value: line.amount),
      },
    ),
  );
}

// Alternate syntax using map
final rows = lines.map((line) => PlutoRow(
  cells: {
    'userId': PlutoCell(value: line.userId),
    'fullName': PlutoCell(value: line.fullName),
    'amount': PlutoCell(value: line.amount),
  },
)).toList();
```

Now you can assign the rows to your grid:

```java
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: PlutoGrid(
      columns: ...,
      rows: rows,
      columnGroups: ...,
      configuration: const PlutoGridConfiguration(),
    ),
  );
}
```